# What will happen if I go higher than common mode range

Tags: amplifier, analog, current-measurement

I am planning to use [MAX9611](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX9611-MAX9612.pdf) as a high-side current sense solution for my circuit. One thing that I do not understand is the common mode range which in the datasheet it says **0 to 60V**:

[image]

Nowhere in the datasheet has been pointed out what will happen if a voltage higher than 60V be applied to the circuit. I am planning to use two different voltages for my LOAD, first 20V@1A and 120V@2A (I have a variable load). In the second mode (120V) I am not interested in sensing the current but I do not want to make a switch to bypass the MAX9611.

So does passing 120V in the circuit above damages the chip?

Comment: Abs max <> Common mode. | Abs max is Abs max. | Common mode voltage is the highest Vin that the highest voltage input can be at and the IC will still be guaranteed to still perform as per spec sheet.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon in this case, common mode is common mode: the maximum common mode voltage into the differential amplifier that has it's inputs at RS+ and RS-

Comment: @JorenVaes Alas, your comment is re-entrant :-) | Note that the data sheet says  (1) Page 13: "Measurement The input common-mode voltage is defined as the average of the voltage at RS+ and RS-. "AND (2) Page 2 top of spec table : "Conditions: :  VSENSE = (VRS+ - VRS-) = 0V. AND (3) Same table "input common mode range = 0-60V."  || Together thse say that if VRS+=VRS- then they may be at 60V as average = 60V. BUT if current flows in Rsense you COULD argue that VRS+ could be eg 61V IF VRS- = 59V so average = 60V BUT you could not then reduce VRsense with VRS+ > 60V. ...

Comment: @JorenVaes ... ie they are saying VRS+ may be at 60V *IF* VRS <= 60V. . || Which is what I said originally. | In the datasheet VVMR of 65V is mentioned but it does not appear in the spec table except as a abs max survival value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assume that smoke will come out if you exceed the Absolute Maximum ratings, **especially** if the data sheet says nothing more about it.

In this particular case, these high voltage pins will have a junction to substrate, that can breakdown like a diode, and they will have resistors down to the input of the sensing amplifier which is driven off the 5v VCC, which could have excessive dissipation. How many more likely ways do you want of blowing the thing up?

If they could have advertised a part capable to 70v, or 120v, you can rest assured that they would have done.

Answer (score 2):

> Nowhere in the datasheet has been pointed out what will happen if a
>   voltage higher than 60V be applied to the circuit

The absolute maximum voltage on the RS pins are 65 volts as per what the data sheet says: -

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I know that but my question is, and in datasheet nothing is written about it, that what will happen if I exceed this voltage. I have two assumption 1) It will fry the chip and destroys it 2) The chip will not produce meaningful output but it stays healthy! so which one is correct?

Comment: My understanding would be: The +/-65V is only applicable if the measuring circuit (MAX9611) is sharing ground with the loads round or the difference between RS+ and RS- is exceeding +/-65V.

Comment: An absolute maximum rating is what it is and all bets are off if you exceed this value - the chip may not fry until 80 volts or a 100 volts so don't go greater than this value or you can expect chip problems. As for sharing ground, if you think that it might be doable to raise all connected circuits to a higher level to prevent the over-voltage happening then good luck to you. One thing all engineers do is this - they don't design circuits that exceed AMRs.

Comment: Thanks again. Yeah, good engineers don't exceed AMR, and I was not planning to do so unless I was absolutely sure it would not cause failure...I guess I have to find a way to stay below 60V common mode voltage.

Comment: A note below the Absolute Maximum Ratings table says "Stresses beyond those listed under “Absolute Maximum Ratings” may cause permanent damage to the device. These are stress ratings only, and functional operation of the device at these or any other conditions beyond those indicated in the operational sections of the specifications is not implied. Exposure to absolute maximum rating conditions for extended periods may affect device reliability."

Answer (score 1):

**Common mode voltage** is the highest Vin that the highest voltage input can be at and the IC will still be guaranteed to still perform as per spec sheet.
See below for why.

---

**Absolute Maximum / ABS MAX** values are those below which the IC is "guaranteed" not to be damaged.

At these values it is NOT guaranteed to operate correctly or at all.
It may - if so you are in luck.
It may APPEAR to - in which case you may (unwisely) THINK that you are in luck.

**Electrical Characteristics** data relates to guaranteed normal operation.

The maximum value in Electrical Characteristics ratings are the highest values at which guaranteed operation can be expected.

Above that magic smoke may happen. At 120V magic smoke or Lot's-wife-pillar-of-salt-imitations can be almost guaranteed.(Or both).

Common mode voltage is defined in the data sheet as (Page 13)

- "The input common-mode voltage is defined as 
  the average of the voltage at RS+ and RS-.

VCM max = 60V.
This is specified under conditions given in the fine print at the top of table at the bottom of page 2. viz

- "Conditions:  VSENSE = (VRS+ - VRS-) = 0V.
- Same table: "input common mode range = 0-60V."

Together these specs say that if VRS+=VRS- then they may both be at 60V
as average = 60V.

BUT if current flows in Rsense you COULD argue that VRS+ could be eg 61V IF VRS- = 59V so the average = 60V. Trying to argue this would be unwise.
You could not then reduce VRsense with VRS+ > 60V.

ie they are saying VRS+ may be at 60V *IF* VRS <= 60V.

(In the datasheet VVMR of 65V is mentioned in discussion but it does not appear in the spec table except as an abs max survival value.)